# Unix : List of files

Tags: bash, unix

**Listing of files based on timings**

User gives date as input. For eg: 20/11/2013 (**dd/mm/yyyy**)

**Output list of files**

- 19/11/2013 - Files created after 10PM (Yesterday)
- 20/11/2013 - Files created before 8AM (Today)

I tried the following :
List of files (**10PM - 7AM for Nov 19 run**)

```
find  . -type f  -exec ls -ltr {} \; | grep -E "Nov 18.22:|Nov 18.23:|Nov 19.00:| Nov 19.01:| Nov 19.02:| Nov 19.03:| Nov 19.04:| Nov 19.05:| Nov 19.06:| Nov 19.07:"
```

Is there any alternative/optimized way to list files without hardcoding the time/date values like(22:,23:,00:) mentioned in above one-liner.

Comment: Check the time based options of the `file` command. Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Just need to list files with above condition ... file command might not help .. let me check !!

Comment: Sorry! I meant the `find` command itself and its time based options! That was a typo!

Comment: I used find itself and command mentioned above is working fine...... but is there any optimzed query (without hardcoding values) which will fetch me the required data...

Comment: `find` allows to specify time intervals, so relative offsets. That was what I had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could control the time-style from `ls` output. Then the condition comparison is easy.

```
find  . -type f  -exec ls -ltr --time-style=+"%Y%m%d%H" {} \; | awk '{if($6>2013111822 && $6<2013111907) print $0}'
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
find  . -type f  -newermt '11/19/2013 20:00:00' -not -newermt '11/20/2013 08:00:00'
```

Comment: Previuosly I followed this :
http://superuser.com/questions/259083/how-dow-i-find-all-log-files-created-between-4-and-7-oclock-this-morning

But -newermt not working in my environment ....is there any other alternative !!

Comment: @Debaditya: what exactly is your environment?

Answer (score 2):

The following could work (with user input date). It uses temporary files for defining time interval and date command for date arithmetics:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Date (dd/mm/yyyy): "
read ddmmyyyy
mmddyyyy=${ddmmyyyy:3:2}/${ddmmyyyy:0:2}/${ddmmyyyy:7:4}
#echo $mmddyyyy

TMP=/tmp/so20089884
touch $TMP.a.$PID $(date -d "$mmddyyyy 08:00")
touch $TMP.z.$PID $(date -d "$mmddyyyy 08:00 - 8 hours")

find . -type f -newer $TMP.z.$PID -not -newer $TMP.a.$PID

rm -f $TMP.[az].$PID
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method with `ls command` 
Try the below one,

**19/11/2013 - Files created after 10PM (Yesterday)**

```
ls -l |  awk -F " " '{if($6 == "Nov" && $7 == "19" && $8 > "22:00") print}'
```

**20/11/2013 - Files created before 8AM (Today)**

```
ls -l |  awk -F " " '{if($6 == "Nov" && $7 == "20" && $8 < "08:00") print}'
```